# TypeError: Cannot read property 'canGoBack' of undefined

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm trying to use `IonRouterOutlet` on `app.component` and here is the code

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";

import { AlertController, IonRouterOutlet, Platform } from "@ionic/angular";
import { SplashScreen } from "@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx";
import { StatusBar } from "@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx";
import { FcmService } from "@core/services/fcm-service/fcm.service";
import { AuthenticationService } from "@core/services/authenticatiion-service/authentication.service";
import { Location } from "@angular/common";
import { Plugins } from "@capacitor/core";

const { App } = Plugins;

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["app.component.scss"],
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild(IonRouterOutlet, { static: true }) routerOutlet: IonRouterOutlet;
  constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private statusBar: StatusBar,
    private fcmService: FcmService,
    private authService: AuthenticationService,
    private alertController: AlertController,
    private location: Location
  ) {
    this.authService.checkToken();
    this.initializeApp();
    this.backButtonEvent();
  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
      this.authService.changeRoutes();
      this.fcmService.initPush();
    });
  }

  backButtonEvent() {
    console.log('back button event');
   

    this.platform.backButton.subscribeWithPriority(10, () => {
      if (!this.routerOutlet.canGoBack()) {
         console.log('cannot');
      }
    });
  }

  async presentAlertConfirm() {
    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
      cssClass: "my-custom-class",
      header: "Confirm",
      message: "Are you sure you want to exit ?",
      backdropDismiss: false,
      buttons: [
        {
          text: "Cancel",
          role: "cancel",
          cssClass: "secondary",
        },
        {
          text: "Logout",
          handler: () => {
            this.authService.logout();
            App.exitApp();
          },
        },
      ],
    });

    await alert.present();
  }
}
```

But every time the back button is pressed event-triggered but `routerOutlet` throws an undefined error when trying to access `canGoBack()`.

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'canGoBack' of undefined`

Any help?

Comment: try changing `@ViewChild(IonRouterOutlet, { static: true })` to `@ViewChild(IonRouterOutlet, { static: false })`

Comment: `static` to true means: to resolve query results before change detection runs, try to change true to false to see.

Comment: changing `static` to false didn't help.

Comment: i even tried with remove static still it's `undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It didn't work inside the `app.component`, But it only works inside other components.

May be because `app.component` is the root component of an Angular app. Correct me if im wrong and explain further if someone knows why.

Answer (score 0):

```
    @ViewChild(IonRouterOutlet, { static: false }) routerOutlet: IonRouterOutlet;

    backButtonEvent(){

    this.platform.backButton.subscribe((event: any) => {
     if (this.routerOutlet && this.routerOutlet.canGoBack()) {
      this.routerOutlet.pop();
     } else {
        App.exitApp();
     }
    });

   }
```

Comment: since `routerOutlet` is undefined this also doesn't work